# Spark - Write DataFrame with custom file name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark (2.4) DataFrame that I want to write as a Pipe separated file. It should be pretty straightforward like so

```
val myDF = spark.table("mySchema.myTable")
myDF.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").options("header", "true").options("delimiter", "|").save("/tmp/myDF")
```

I get a `part-*.csv` file in `/tmp/myDF`.

So far, so good. But I actually want the file name to be something specific, e.g. `/tmp/myDF.csv`

But giving this String in `save` will just create a dir called `myDF.csv` and create the `part*.csv` file in there.

Is there a way to write the DataFrame with a specific name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Spark

You can rename the file later accessing the fileSystem

```
val directory = new File(/tmp/myDF)

if (directory.exists && directory.isDirectory) {
   val file = directory.listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".csv")).head
   file.renameTo("myDF.csv")
}
```